# How to set conditioned default value in ion select using data from API

Tags: typescript, angular7, ionic4

I am new with angular 7 and Ionic 4.

I am developing a mobile app, I am working with an API, I have a list of tasks and when I click on a task, a modal opens, showing the task info, in this modal there are some fields that are  elements, for example assigned user, I want to set the ion-select default value depending in which assigned user was selected when the task was created.

Summarizing, I want that if a user was assigned, it will be set as default in the ion-select when the modal appears.

HTML file:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-label>Asigned User:</ion-label>
    <ion-select placeholder="Asigned User" formControlName="assignedUserId" > 
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let user of simpleUsers|async;" [value]="user.id" (ionChange)="setUser(user.id)">
        {{user.lastName}} {{user.firstName}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

TS file:

```
this.taskForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'title':[null],
  'description' : [null],
  'descriptionHtml':[null],
  'assignedUserId': [null],
  'deadline':[null],
  'deadlineType':[null],
  'fromDate':[null],
  'clientId':[null]
});

// ...

async getTaskInfo() {
  this.taskId = this.navParams.get('taskId');

  await this.api.getTaskById(this.taskId).subscribe(result => {
    this.task = result;
  });
}

async getCompanies() {
  this.clients = this.api.getCompanies();
}

async getSimpleUsers() {
  this.simpleUsers = this.api.getSimpleUsers();
}

async setUser(userId) {
  this.assignedUserId = userId;
}

async setClient(clientId) {
  this.clientId = clientId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're binding the `ion-select` to the `assignedUserId` control and the `[value]` property from the `ion-select-option` points to the `user.Id`, seems like the only thing you'd need to do to initialize the `ion-select` is to set the value of the `assignedUserId` control as soon as you get the details of that task. It'd be something like this:

```
// ...

async getTaskInfo() {

  this.taskId = this.navParams.get('taskId');

  // If you want to use await, getTaskById() should return a promise
  this.task = await this.api.getTaskById(this.taskId).toPromise();

  // I'm assuming the task has an userId property
  if(this.task && this.task.userId) {

    // Update the value of the control
    this.taskForm.get('assignedUserId').setValue(this.task.userId);    

  }

}

// ...
```